# Persisting data in a ViewModel passed to a form in a partial view and then back to Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, forms, razor

I am building an application that contains a simple form to add Comments to Posts.

As other components in my project allow users to submit comments and use this form, I have decided to contain the form within a partial view, as so:

```
@model Assignment_3.ViewModels.DetailViewModel

        @using (Html.BeginForm("AddComment", "Comments", new { m = Model })) 
        {
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.CommentSubmission.Translation, new { @class = "control-label" })
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.CommentSubmission.Translation, new { @class = "form-control" })

                    </div>
                </div>

           <div class="col-md-2">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.CommentSubmission.LanguageId, new { @class = "control-label" })
                        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.CommentSubmission.LanguageId,
                 Model.CommentSelectListItems, "", new { @class = "form-control" })
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.CommentSubmission.Body, 7, 15, new { @class = "form-control" })
                       </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-1">
                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" value="AddComment" />
                </div>

        }
```

Views that link to this partial view pass their ViewModel (DetailViewModel) to it. This model contains information about the Post, such as PostId, that the comments relate to.

The main View links to the partial view as so:

```
@Html.Partial("_AddComment", Model);
```

Once the user submits, the form calls it's action method returning the view it inherited from the "Post" page:

(Controller)

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult AddComment(DetailViewModel view)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            _context.CommentSubmissions.Add(view.CommentSubmission);
            _context.SaveChanges();

             return RedirectToAction("Detail", "Posts", new { id = view.CommentSubmission.IdiomId });
        }
        view.Init(_context);
        return View(view);
    }
```

What I've noticed happening is that whilst the ViewModel does return with the information collected in the form, it does not carry over the original information from the Post's DetailViewModel. Consequently, when I call "RedirectToAction", id is null as information concerning the PostID has been lost.

I'm still new new to MVC and help persisting that / or other optimized approaches would appreciated.

---

ANSWER (thanks to msoliman):

Added to Form:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Post.PostId)
```

Updated Controller to:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult AddTranslation(DetailViewModel view)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            view.CommentSubmission.IdiomId = view.Post.PostId;

            _context.TranslationSubmissions.Add(view.CommentSubmission);
            _context.SaveChanges();

            return RedirectToAction("Detail", "Posts", new { id = view.CommentSubmission.PostId });

        }

        //view.Init(_context);
        return View(view);

    }
```

Comment: I did not get what you mean, however I just need to highlight that only the controls inside your form should be sent over to the server side. would you please edit ur question again and highlight the exact problem you have to be able to solve for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I understood your question, however if I misunderstood please leave a comment and I would be more than happy to update me answer and help you.

You're trying to send data of post while your form only has comments fields, if you want to add field from post add a hidden field of the data you want to pass to the form. also make sure your comment view model has this field.

Add for example something like this inside your form

```
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.PostID)
```

Also you should've defined `PostID` field inside it Comment's View model (`DetailViewModel`) to be passed from your view or form action to the controller.

Comment: I'm trying now. Thank you very much - I've also updated my question a little.

Comment: add hidden field to "CommentSubmission.IdiomId" and put it inside ur form and it should work fine - make sure you pass it to the view when u load the form, if it works and my answer was helpful please mark my answer as correct, if not plz  leave a comment

Comment: Thank very much again! I've updated my answer with the code that now works for your reference and additional thoughts, if any. Do I understand correctly that it's because a form will only carry the information inside of it to the Controller and consequently, you need to persist data from the ViewModel inside of the form?

Comment: @Scribbio That is true however only the fields that are inside ur form will be passed through to your controller, view model is used only to avoid security issue as if you use directly the model, any user may go and inject html code and fill ur model manually to be saved into database. viewmodel should have only the fields you want your customer to fill and retrieve from your database model, glad you manage it to work :)